# Need help modifying code to connect to MongoDB Atlas instead of localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am currently learning CRUD and I've made a simple react app where you can create, edit and delete jokes, using MongoDB. This is currently working fine with MongoDB running on my own PC and connecting through localhost but now I'd like to upload my react front-end to a shared hosting site and have the back-end running on Atlas. I've already created a cluster on Atlas but I honestly have no idea how to modify my current code to connect to Atlas instead of localhost.

This is what one of my react components looks like: (set up with localhost) but they all look similar of course, so if I can get this component working, I should be able to get them all working.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Create = () => {

    const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/jokes";
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((jokes) => {
                setJokes(jokes);
            });
    }, []);

    function createData() { // Used in onclick event further down
        const Textarea1 = document.getElementById("Textarea1")
        const Textarea2 = document.getElementById("Textarea2")
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/jokes/', {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                overskrift: Textarea1.value,
                jokeTekst: Textarea2.value,
            })

        })
        console.log("joke created")
        alert("Joke has been created")
        window.location.href = "/Admin";
    }

    return (
        <div className="container jokecreate">

            <div className="row text-center">

                <div className="col-3"></div>

                <div className="col-6">

                <div><h2>Create New Joke</h2></div>
                
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea1" rows="1" placeholder="Name of joke" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea2" rows="3" placeholder="Joke text" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div className="col-3"></div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <Link to="/Admin"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Back</button>  </Link>

                <button type="button" onClick={createData} class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Create
```

And here is the connection information I have from Atlas:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://****:****@cluster0.cdem6.mongodb.net/jokes?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

Which includes username and password (hidden here with ****) of a user that has read and write access.

So my question is can I merge that into my current code and make it work as-is or do I need more steps to make it all work correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

Comment: posting username and password publicly is a bad idea. please change the credentials ASAP.

Comment: thank you - they are hidden now

Comment: THEY ARE NOT HIDDEN. Everybody can still see the history, also scrapers et. al. might already extracted those information. CHANGE THEM!

Comment: Ahh of course - thank you again Jonas Wilms. I've deleted the user from my database.

Comment: Read the documentation on IP whitelisting.

Comment: My question wasn't about IP whitelisting. I already have that set up and working. I can connect to and modify my database using MongoDBCompas but I need help accessing it from my react front-end.